# Regex to extract text from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string:

```js
const myString = "This is my comment content. [~firstName.lastName]";
```

What is a javascript regex to extract the "firstName" and "lastName"?

What is a javascript regex to extract the content minus the "[~firstName.lastName]"?

I'm rubbish with Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could target each name separately. `match` will return the complete match as the first element of the array, and the groupings specified by the `(` and `)` in the regex as the subsequent elements.

```js
const str = 'This is my comment content. [~firstName.lastName]';
const regex = /\[~(.+)\.(.+)\]/;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Or you could target just the characters within the brackets and then `split` on the `.`.

```js
const str = 'This is my comment content. [~firstName.lastName]';
const regex = /\[~(.+)\]/;
console.log(str.match(regex)[1].split('.'));
```

Comment: This may fail for multiple occurrences of the pattern `[~firstName.lastName]`.

Comment: I only base my answers on the information provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const myString = "This is my comment content. [~firstName.lastName]";
const first = myString.match(/.*\~(.*)\./)[1]
const last = myString.match(/.*\.(.*)]/)[1]
const both = myString.match(/.*\~(.*)\]/)[1]

console.log(first)
console.log(last)
console.log(both)
```

[Here's a good website for regex help](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```js
let myString = "This is my comment content. [~firstName.lastName] and the original name is [~John.Doe]";
const regex = /\[~([^\]]+)\.([^\]]+)\]/g;

let match = regex.exec(myString);
const names = [];

while(match !== null) {
  names.push({firstName: match[1], lastName: match[2]});
  match = regex.exec(myString);
}

// Remove the pattern from the original string.
myString = myString.replace(regex, '');

console.log(names, myString);
```

This code will find all the matches found for the pattern.